How to automatically obtain .net metrics in datadog using dogstatsD
We are using app.metrics to generate internal performance metrics for our applications' operations.  These use the .Report.ToStatsDUdp to transmit to datadog's dogstatsD.
This works correctly.
We have added the ".NET runtime Metrics" integration to Datadog.
Our application runs in containers in kubernetes inside Azure.  Datadog seems to automatically inject dogstatsD into our containers when they are deployed.
Following Datadog's Documentation, we have set DD_RUNTIME_METRICS_ENABLED=true.
Based on the documentation we're expecting Datadog to somehow extract the .net performance metrics from the CLR, but none of them seem to populate.  We see our own metrics, but none of the promised .net metrics like runtime.dotnet.cpu.system
Has anyone had to implement this before?  Is there anything we've missed?
